# Possible to Migrate external mailbox to new exchange installation?

Tags: email, exchange

I am looking for a way to migrate an externally hosted Exchange mailbox into a new Exchange installation. The situation is basically this:

- Current mailbox is hosted on exchange 2016, but I have limited access to the Exchange configuration. Essentially, the only access I have to this mailbox is through the email client I use for it.
- New exchange installation is fully managed by myself and I have full access to it all.

I'd like to programatically be able to migrate from the externally hosted into the new internally managed one.

I've seen various "free trial" software packages offering the ability to do this, but not much else.

Anybody done this before without additional software?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Agree with what joeqwerty has replied above, you just migrate mailbox's content to your new exchange not the actual mailbox. If you migrate content of mailbox to the new exchange server, you could create a new inbox rule to route the message from the external mailbox to your new exchange mailbox. A inbox rule looks like below:

[image]

Comment: This is potentially a good idea, the problem is that the old and new mailboxes are both of the same email address. The other problem here is that I don't think this will create the folder structure on the new mailbox?

Answer (score 0):

At the end of the day, you're not migrating the actual mailbox, you're migrating the content of the mailbox. For that you can use any one of a number of third party tools, or simply export the current mailbox to a PST file and import it into the new mailbox.

Comment: Thanks but this doesn't help, I've said i want to do this programatically. I don't want to use third party tools and export / import through outlook is a manual process I want to avoid.

Comment: With only client app access to the source Exchange server, there isn't a way to do it programatically.